# Inheritance from a template c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a question about a code that I have recently took in my hands. I just want to know if in C++ templates paradigm it is correct or useful to do the following inheritance (just 3 classes as an example):

---

```
template< class I, class P, class D, unsigned int ID = 0 >
class PathFilter : public Filter< I, P, 1 >
{
...
}
```

---

```
template< class I, class A, unsigned int N = 1 >
class Filter : public Algorithm< I, A >
{
...
}
```

---

```
template< class I, class A >
class Algorithm : public A //This line
{
   ...
}
```

---

My question is specifically about the inheritance in the third example. Is it useful to make it so 'generic' and not precise? It is a good choice to compromise understandable code by a more generic code?

I ask firstly because I'm not an expert in C++ templates, but also because I see this code difficult to understand using templates (usually the names of the templates say nothing about its content). Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is a *mixin class* (in particular, your class `Algorithm` is the one).

As a reference you can consult, for instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern.

Indeed you are specifying "certain functionality (specified by `A`) to be inherited or just reused by a subclass (i.e. `Algorithm`)".  (cit. from the first article)

In other words, you are making yourself (or your user) free to add or change behavior to `Algorithm` somehow "afterwards". Your real gain is to achieve such a flexibility relying just on the compiler and not on some *dynamic-binding-like mechanism* (e.g. overriding of virtual functions). Your final class `Algorithm<A>`, in fact, is built at compile time and it  is *possibly*  as efficient as the class you would have obtained writing `Algorithm<A>` explicitly (i.e. explicitly including the policy `A` in `Algorithm` writing it *by hand*).

**EDIT**:

I would also suggest to give a look to this wikipedia page about policy based design ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design ).

There, policies names (your `A`) appear in a clear form, with clear names, as wisely advised by @full.stack.ex.

Comment: So, if that's what you want, fine. As to readability, true, there's a tradition of naming the template parameters weirdly - I, P, A, etc. But you don't have to :). Give them better names and they may become self-descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have a question. I understand the use of a general and abstract definition of some functionalities in a "higher" class. But the main objective of a template is not to generalize parameter types? So what I'm saying at the end is that I can pass almost everything to this higher class and conserve a lower-hierarchy functions. At the end I will have a very restricted set of objects that can inherit (maybe one) the lower functions, am I wrong? It is not an impractical way to define that genericity?

Comment: You're right. Surely just a specific set of classes `A` fits in  `Algorithm<A>` eventually allowing compilation (those `A` must somehow <i>implement</i> an interface specified by `Algorithm<>`). 

Now you are using template for design purposes. What you want to do is to write `Algorithm<>` once, and have several algorithms (e.g. `Algorithm<RungeKutta>`, `Algorithm<Symplectic>`,...) just writing small pieces of code more (i.e. classes `RungeKutta`, `Symplectic`...).

Somehow you are still general with respect to the type.

Comment: Of course the types `RungeKutta` or `Symplectic` can be defined by you or by a user of your code.

Again, the main point is to avoid coupling between `Algorithm` and `A` (which you can achieve through inheritance and virtual functions) at run-time (possibly losing performance). (Of course to my best knowledge).

Comment: Well..thanks again,but I don't understand your example :P.However,in your case we can say that Algorithm implements (inherits) RungeKutta or Symplectic..doesn't matter which one of the classes and of course there I will need a generic function that can be called independently of what I'm using. But again, that means that I can put whatever I want in the top of the hierarchy maybe destroying all the semantic inheritance as for example saying that Algorithm is a 'child' of RungeKutta!It's like saying that the definition of an algorithm come from their examples... That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Look at the example in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design .

it is not really a matter of <i>inheritance</i> in the standard sense. It is more like <i>compile time modularity</i>. Indeed you should look at `Algorithm<RungeKutta>` as your RungeKutta class. Because it shared semantics with `Algorithm<Symplectic>` you wrote `Algorithm<>` in general.

Furthermore the modularity is compile-time solved, so no speed losses..

Comment: Yes, it is quite similar. But at the end as you see, the classes have a common 'message' method. So they are restricted, and should be described by other inheritance or an interface as you said. But, at the end it seems to me that I don't gain to much than including the classes in the hierarchy. Specially in this case that I present where the patter is applied at the top of the tree ... i think ..

Comment: That's right, if there is not interface there is no point (because you can't use it!).

You allow for dependencies on `A` at the top of the tree when your class `PathFilter` should be given to a user of yours who needs to specify it a-posteriori  (and, moreover, who is not concerned about the whole structure of your code).

Comment: Thanks once again for your answers.I've looked more in detail what the policy-based design is and it's very interesting as a pattern, but difficult to follow. Here I found a good schematic guide about that http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/11/28/policy-based-design-in-c/ helped also with Alexandrescu's book about Modern C++ Programming.Actually, the only thing that I don't see clearly is that every policies should be defined by a general interface as we were talking in the other posts.But well..I'll try to figure out  the advantages using this approach in the project I have right now.Buen dia

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18155/discussion-between-acorbe-and-ricardo-a-corredor)